# on my homepage I want to show a "news" section with posts tagged "news" from the last 30 days. How?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

As the title says, in the homepage (index.php) I want to add a section for the news which is populated by "news" tagged posts and it only shows posts from the last 30 days. if no posts has been published in the last 30 days then the news section is empty and disappears.

- how do I query those posts from last 30 days? do I use a new WP_query or pre_get_posts?
- how do I write it to make the section not show up if there are no news?
  I'm guessing it's enough to create the div inside the loop instead of outside using

  ```
           if ( have_posts() ) : 
               echo '<div class="newsdiv">','<ul>'
               while ( have_posts() ) : the_post('<li>','</li>'); 

               // Display post content

                   the_title('<h2 class="news">','</h2>');
                   the_thumbnail();
                   the_excerpt();
               endwhile; 
               echo '</ul>','</div>'
           endif; 
           ?>
  ```

i'm sorry for banal questions or mistakes, i'm trying to learn wordpress and php. If you could add some explanation with your answer it would make it easier for me to learn the why and not just how.

Answer (score 1):

Using WP_Query add next params:

```
$args= array( 
  'date_query' => array(
    array(
      'after' => '-30 days',
      'column' => 'post_date',
    ),
  ),
);
$your_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

It will grab posts `post_type => 'post'` for the last 30 days

```
if($your_query->have_posts()) : 
  // Code to display your news
  while($your_query->have_posts()) : $your_query->the_post();
    // Single news
  endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
else: 
  // No posts
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using WP_Query like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'posts',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'  => '-30 days',
            'column' => 'post_date',
        ),
    ),
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    
    // add your loop content here

    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
    // Reset query incase we want to use another query on the same page
endif;
```